# Creating helper table by filtering out zero-values

Tags: google-sheets

Consider the following table in Google Sheets:

```
   | A   B
 --+-------
 1 | A   5
 2 | B   3
 3 | C   6
 4 | D   0
 5 | E   0 
 6 | F   7
 7 | G   0
 8 | H   2
 9 | I   0
10 | J   0
```

I would like to put this data in a bar chart, but if I select the full table as range, I also get the values added where column B = `0`. So I need to filter those out by creating a helper table where only those values are listed where column B > `0`:

```
   | A   B
 --+-------
 1 | A   5
 2 | B   3
 3 | C   6
 4 | F   7
 5 | H   2
```

What formula can I use to get this output, so that I can base the chart on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try simple:

```
=FILTER(A:B, B:B<>0)
```

or:

```
=FILTER(A:B, B:B>0)
```